# Android show sorted data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

my question is more like an idea of how can I achieve something which I want to do in my application. Imagine that I have two tables in my sqlite database which I'm populating from web and they look like this :

```
|    GENRES      |           |   GENRES_LANG    |
|   genres_id    |           |    genres_id     |
|     count      |           |    lang_code     |
                             |      title       |
```

And here is sample data which I have on these tables :

```
GENRES: genres_id : 1, count : 5
        genres_id: 2, count:4
        genres_id: 3, count: 6

GENRES_LANG: genres_id : 1, lang_code: en_ES , title: Atitle1InSpanish
             genres_id: 1, lang_code: en_US, title: Btitle1InEnglish
             genres_id: 2, lang_code: en_US, title :  Ctitle2OnlyInEnglish
             genres_id: 3, lang_code: en_ES, title: Dtitle3InSpanish
             genres_id: 3, lang_code: en_US, title: Etitle3InEnglish
```

and etc.

So the things which I want to achieve is to show genres by their title depending on users locale code. For example if my phone's locale is set to Spanish (en_ES), I want to sort all genres by their title and show them, but if there is a genre which is available only for users which locale code is English (en_US), I want to show it too, no matter if my current locale is Spanish or something else and I want it to be sorted too. So the result which I want to see is somethings like this :

If my locale is set to en_ES:

```
Atitle1InSpanish   |   Ctitle2OnlyInEnglish   |   Dtitle3InSpanish
```

Any ideas how can I do this?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help/suggestions/advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT genres_id, lang_code, title FROM GENRES_LANG WHERE lang_code=? OR lang_code='en_US'`

Use that with `rawQuery()`, passing the locale as the first element of the string array that is the second parameter to `rawQuery()`.